# Check if table exist and then include php else not

Tags: php, sql

Is there a way where I can inlcude a php file if a table exists in my database whose name is the same as $current_product_name. This is my code where I am already connected to the database.

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $current_product_name";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SHOW TABLES LIKE '".$current_product_name."'"))
{
 if($result->num_rows == 1) { include_once("getProduct.php");}
 }
 else { echo "Product not available."; }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easily.
Query your database to see if table exists. If it does you'll get a return of true. If true include that.

Comment: IF EXISTS? is that what you mean? My php throws an error.